# serving two websites with nginx

Tags: http, curl, nginx

I want to run a simple nginx page that serves two pages.  One from folder ~/A and one from ~/B

Each folder runs a copy of Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` in ports 1000 and 2000

Each file has a single file called `index.html` with text **Hello World!**

```
server {    

        listen 80;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location /   {
                root ~/A;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1000;
        }

        location /B/ {
                root ~/B;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
        }

}
```

Unfortunately `curl http://localhost/B/index.html` returns a 404.

```
<head>
<title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error response</h1>
<p>Error code 404.
<p>Message: File not found.
<p>Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
</body>
```

What is wrong with my nginx conf file?  Why can't it route properly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want use `alias ~/B` instead of `root ~/B` because your `location /B/` will try `~/B/B`. See [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) and [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) documentations.

Answer (score 0):

you can open the nginx debug log and s.
i think this url will matches 'location \'  and goto A.

Comment: try to mv location 'location /B/' before the 'location /'  or change 'location /' to 'location /A/'